# Google Charts size in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am running into some problems getting consistent size for a simple google bar chart.

I have a directive that displays some information and I want to include a bar chart of the data

```
app.directive('prodpercentiles', function($compile, $http, $timeout) {
return {
  scope: {
    'data': '=',
    'help': '@',
    'id': '@',
    'cardtitle': '@',
  },
  templateUrl: '/static/prod_percentiles.html',
  controller: function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.elem = angular.element($('#'+$scope.id)).find('#chart')[0];

    $scope.draw_chart = function() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      $scope.chart_obj = new google.charts.Bar($scope.elem);
      //console.log($scope.elem)
      data.addColumn('string','Percentile')
      data.addColumn('number','Product Count')
      $scope.data.percentiles.sort(function(a,b) { return a.val > b.val;}).forEach(function(x) {
        data.addRow([x.val.toString(), x.count])
      })
      var options = {
        legend: { position: 'none'},
        title: 'Number of products in each percentile',
      };
      $scope.chart_obj.draw(data, options);
    }
```

There are two of these directives on the page with different data. The behavior that I am seeing is that on the initial load the height and width of each bar chart is the default. The only way I can get the chart to display with a different size is by statically inputting height / width into options. I would like to avoid this, for some reason none of the styling that I am applying to the #chart element is being used.

However, I've set up a resize listener to re-draw the chart and it works fine:

```
$(window).resize(function(){$scope.draw_chart()});
```

So after I resize the window, both charts look good. Now, I've already sank enough time on this and I just want to finish this. I am trying to hack around this by forcing the resize when it is loading the chart like so.

```
angular.element(window).trigger('resize')
```

There is a UI button that switches from table to bar chart, it calls the draw_chart and resize. This should have been a sufficient work around.

However, now when I toggle the bar chart on one of the directives, it actually fixes the chart in the other one and vise versa. Does anyone know what this can be? I am really out of ideas here. If I actually resize the main browser window they both look fine.

The real issue here is that the chart is not being properly sized on the initial load. I've tried to put a small delay in there in case the DOM is not fully there when it tries to render, but it didn't help.

The second issue is with the resize.

Comment: http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/

Comment: Same issue, size is only fixed after a browser resize.

Comment: If you have an ng-show or ng-hide anywhere on or above the chart, it will render the chart into a container of undefined size. To fix I usually either use ng-if so the chart does not exist at all until displayed, or set a fixed size with the chart options.